# Setting turtles in parcel without sprout

Tags: netlogo

I been looking for the way to place each turtle in a parcel, but I do not want to have two turtles in  the same parcel. Does anybody know how to do it?. (Without using sprout).

Comment: From the "without using sprout", I assume this is homework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have more patches than turtles, all you need is:

```
ask turtles [
  move-to one-of patches with [ not any? turtles-here ]
]
```

#### Interesting side note:

People are often tempted to stick [`other`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#other) in there, as in:

```
; bad code:
ask turtles [
  move-to one-of patches with [ not any? other turtles-here ]
]
```

but this calls `other` within the patch context, so *it doesn't actually do anything*. To achieve the desired effect of not excluding the patch that the turtle is already on, you could write:

```
ask turtles [
  let me self
  move-to one-of patches with [ not any? turtles-here with [ self != me ] ]
]
```

Whether or not it is worth the trouble depends on your particular circumstances.

Finally, note that:

```
; bad code:
ask turtles [
  move-to one-of patches with [ not any? [ other turtles-here ] of myself ]
]
```

would *not* work either because [`turtles-here`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#turtles-here) would then be called in the turtle's context instead of being called in the patch context.